# Importance of PHP update, if Magento is patched?

Tags: magento-1.8

Could someone reconfirm, if magento 1.8 is running  php 5.3 but has all the latest SUPEE patches installed. Is it CRUCIAL to install  php 5.6 or even php 7.0 ?

I am afraid the maximum php version magento 1.8 can handle is 5.4 (with patch). 5.5-5.6 may cause extension to break.

Is it a high risk leaving at 5.3 or possibly update to 5.4 but always keeping store patched with latest SUPEE? I realized almost 25% of the web run 5.3 at 2017.
To my knowledge SUPEE patches prevent magento form being hacked, but outdated PHP framework vulnerabilities usually compose of DoS attacks.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not install php 5.6 or 7.0 while running Magento 1.8**

Magento 1.8 is only compatible with PHP 5.3 (or 5.4 if you installed the patch/update).

PHP 5.3 has not been supported since late 2014.  PHP 5.4 has not been supported since late 2015. See: http://php.net/supported-versions.php

It is possible to use php 5.4 with Magento 1.8 (see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ce1.8_release-notes.html#php54).  Magento 1.9 is only supported on PHP up to 5.4.  This still leaves you pretty-far behind.

Magento has been focusing on Magento 2 with the community edition, so I doubt you'll see a php 5.5 or 5.6 compatible version or patch released.

Your best bet is to start looking at migrating to Magento 2.x and running PHP 7.  It's a major shift, but it will put you on current software that is currently maintained.  Most third-party developers are releasing their extensions compatible with Magento 2, so your extensions may be available already.

Comment: I will be planning m2 migration but it's going to take quite a bit some time (6-8 months). From you experience, do you its critically BAD running outdated php 5.3? SUPEE  patches are always installed.

Comment: Is it critical? No; **however**, that depends upon your infrastructure and how well you harden your system.  In most cases, you're probably fine.  If you keep a good review of your logs and actively monitor your resources, you should be able to see any issues that may or may not come up.  There is always a possibility of something happening.

Comment: I appreciate the response! Short and concise.